# Python processing 3 why is current working directory different sometimes?

Tags: python, processing

I am getting this error sometimes when working on mac in Processing for Python. Seemingly for no reason, sometimes the current working directory becomes what you see in the image while other times it is the working directory of the folder the pyde file is in as it should be.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

[image: Python processing error.]

Comment: Are you using a special program for visualizing your game? That's probably where the issue lies, it's for sure not the python code. Maybe try closing your file after opening it? This could be a lot of stuff. I would Google "how to access files in python in <my_game_developer_program>"

Comment: A common beginner error is assuming that Python will run in the directory where you saved the script. But that's not how it works; it will run in *your* current working directory.

Comment: As the name says, the "current working directory" is the directory you are currently working in ("where the shell is"), not the directory where your script always is.

Comment: Related: [Is there any other way to load image in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64835525/is-there-any-other-way-to-load-image-in-pygame/64835607#64835607)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to avoid problems like these that I always try to use absolute paths. I would suggest you try something like this for file paths:

```
import os

# This will be the path to your .py file
FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# This will be the path to your text file, if it is in the same directory as the .py
LEVELS_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(FILE_PATH, "levels.txt")
```

Then, instead of your current open statement you could have:

```
f = open(LEVELS_FILE_PATH, 'r')
```

Comment: As a sidenote to avoid problems you should look into using `with open() as` or at the very least make sure your text file is always closed properly

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue in processing 3. If you run the code before saving it, the file will be written to the "/private/..." directory. To resolve this, simply save the file before executing it, and the issue will be resolved.